# Generalised hypergeometric function $_4F_3$ at unit argument

Tags: special-functions

Is there a way to simplify the following generalised hypergeometric function evaluated at unit argument

$$
\, _4F_3\left(-n,3+n,\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{3};2,-\frac{1}{3}-n,\frac{8}{3}+n;1\right)
$$

with $n\geq0$ being an integer?

Comment: Might be worth trying Dougall's formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function

That covers quite a few of these kind of problems. Will want three of the parameters to be the same value so they cancel out.

Comment: I thought Dougall's formula was only valid for the $_7F_6$...

Comment: That's why you need to cancel some of the terms out, i.e. 
$$
\;_7 F_6(a,b,c,d,1,1,1;e,f,g,1,1,1;1) = \;_4 F_3(a,b,c,d;e,f,g;1)
$$
although it might not be as easy as that. Just an idea.

Comment: That is a simple idea that I did not think about. Thanks, will try.

Comment: Alas, it does not seem to work. Thanks for the tip anyway.